# Change Object Size - Android < 4.3

Tags: css, svg, android-browser

I am testing my website with *Android browser* on *Android 4.3*, and the `<object>` clearly does not work like the other plattform. The SVG is being scaled, most likely to it's original size. For some reason it does not scale to the parent `div`.

[image: The issue]

As you see it's both the logo and some white objects below. These are supposed to be circles, but just shows a certain part of the object.

I refer to Can I Use which says `<object>` is not supported with Android 4.3 and older.

Example of an object:

```
<object data="#.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
     <img src="#.png" alt="Text">
</object>
```

As you see I have a fallback, but it clearly does not work. It rather takes the SVG-file... I have tried setting the *object* to the following:

```
height: 100% auto;
```

But that did not work.

I have also tried setting it to exact sizes with `px`, even though this is something I don't want. This was more like a test to see if it helped.

```
width: 50px
height: 50px;
```

Please see [page](http://goo.gl/9IsTIl) if you have troubles understanding. But note that you must be using an *Android Browser* with *Android 4.3* or older.

I am looking for a solution that makes the SVG or Object fit inside the div. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by making all SVG non-interative, and using `<img>` combined with script fallbacks to png version:

```
<img src="#.svg" onerror="this.src='#.png'">.
```